# Prevent Feedback Loop / Catch22 Java Recursion

Tags: java, recursion

I am trying to detect and prevent an object from containing itself in a form of recursion.

Example:
`Product A` contains a list of parts, some of which are of the type `Product`. When adding a `Part` to the list of parts that `Product A` contains, I want to verify it is not itself AND any of the product's parts don't eventually lead back to being `Product A`

```
productA -> part1, productB
productB -> part1, part2, productC
productC -> part3

productC cannot contain productA, productB, or productC
productB cannot contain productA or productB
productA cannot contain productA
```

This is what I have so far. Currently, it works -- sometimes.

```java
class Part {
  protected final long id;
  ...
  public final boolean equals(Object o) {
    ... // ide generated generic stuff
    return this.id == other.id; 
    // which is ultimately (this == o) in most use cases
  }
}

class final Product extends Part {

  List<? extends Part> parts;

  private boolean catch22(Product checkAgainst) {
    Set<? extends Product> products 
            = new HashSet(checkAgainst.parts.stream()
            .filter(e -> e.getClass().equals(getClass()))
            .collect(Collectors.toSet()));
    for (Product product: products) {
      if (this.equals(product)) {
        return true;
      }
      return catch22(product);
    }
    return false;
    // I have a feeling that I'm this is going to the bottom of the first
    // element in the set as it goes down the line until it finishes the
    // loop and then returning false when it hasn't finished.
  }

  public void add(Part part) {
    if (this.equals(part)) {  
      return;
    }
    if (part instanceof Product) {  // use Class.isAssignableFrom?
      Product product = (Product) part;
      if (catch22(product)) {
        return;
      }
    }
    parts.add(part);
  }
}
```

Also, any improvements to implementation are welcome.

Comment: I >>think<< you are trying to detect a violation of one of the standard "containment" invariants; i.e. that an object cannot "contain" itself.  (In this case via the "parts" relationship.)  Is that correct?

Comment: What is your 'catch22' method meant to do? Can you please explain its purpose?

Comment: Yes.  That's much better.

Comment: You say it works 'sometimes'. Writing some unit tests would enable you to keep track of which situations it works in, which it doesn't, and avoid creating the latter when you fix the former. You could also show us where it doesn't work. (my 2c: you always return the first time round your product loop)

Comment: @tgdavies First: it filters out any of the non-`Product` elements out of the part's list as the those elements will not have a `parts` variable. Second: it checks if any of those elements are this, if it is this, it returns true, else it continues recursively until there are no more "building block" products and it's all just `Part`s the set will be empty and it will return false..  And what do you mean first time around the production loop?  -- the unit tests are very random -- I can write two very similar cases and get different results. (There is however 1 that is consistently wrong) A -> A

Comment: @tgdavies I believe it's random because the hash is different for each set. So it has to do with how it's ending or going down the rabbit hole

Comment: catch22 takes a productToAddAsPart, and returns true if the product we are trying to add it to is contained in productToAddAsPart, either directly or transitively. The first thing catch22 does is get a set of the products which are parts of productToAddAsPart. Then we want to check that each of those products is not `this` and that each of those products doesn't contain this (which we do by calling catch22). However, we never check any product other than the first, because catch22 returns after the first recursive call to catch22, even if it returned false and we need to check the next product

Comment: @DavidFisher yes, because you are only checking the first member of the set, the result will depend on the ordering of the set.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for (Product product: products) {
      if (this.equals(product)) {
        return true;
      }
      return catch22(product);
}
```

should be:

```
boolean catch22(Product checkAgainst) {
    if (this.equals(checkAgainst)) {
        return true;
    }
    Set<? extends Product> products 
                = new HashSet(checkAgainst.parts.stream()
                .filter(e -> e.getClass().equals(getClass()))
                .collect(Collectors.toSet()));
    for (Product product: products) {
        if (catch22(product)) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```